Send paid media aiogram 3.10
How to send blurred paid media in channel? Here is me code, but I cannot find solution https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/types/input_media_photo.html
import asyncio
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.filters import CommandStart
from aiogram.types import Message, InputPaidMediaPhoto

 

TOKEN = "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"


PHOTO_URL = 'https://i.imgur.com/i2CvF2q.jpeg' 

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher()


@dp.message(CommandStart())
async def command_start(message: Message):
    await message.answer_paid_media(star_count=500, media=[InputPaidMediaPhoto(media=PHOTO_URL)])


async def main():
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

